# Detecting where vocals start in a song?

Tags: signal-processing, audio

what would be the best way to detect where the vocals in a song start? I just need the start time for vocals. Extreme precision is not necessary. Speed is more important.

Any clues to papers or algorithms (if such exist) are greatly appreciated.. Also looking for recommendations on which framework / language fits best for this.

Comment: you know human beings can do a vast range of things using their voice, including Beatboxing, Growling, "Normal" Singing, Throat Singing, and even animal voice imitation. All of these could occur during a _song_, thus potentially being _vocals_, or not. Of course, this is an interesting question, but please be specific in your question, and also [state what your research effort has brought up so far](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/179891).

Comment: valid comment about research. I will definitely update once I get somewhere.. Before getting feedback from answers below, I was thinking of just doing the pitch detection of a human voice frequency (starts from around 85Hz - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_frequency ). But clearly the links from below can provide more insight into that. As far as vocals, I am interested in any kind of sounds produced by human voice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*** SPOILER: ANSWER IS NOT BELOW ***

Since I plan to do something similar to this, I did a little research on my own on the subject, and found out that there are some exact numeric techniques that MIGHT be able to do that.

I'll list the references, and let you as the reader decide if that's a right way to go.  It all has to do with vocal audio feature extraction, and finding there vocal features ARE in audio data.

You can start here, but it really doesn't lead anywhere, but could be useful to see what are you into :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection

Then, some articles about speaker recognition:

Here, there is a primer that you need to know about `mel frequency cepstral coefficients` (MFCC) feature extraction.

http://www.speaker-recognition.org/navAlg.html

Then, for example, this:

http://www.iccce.co.in/Papers/ICCCECE358.pdf

I know that none of them lead directly to the solution to your problem, but at least you'll be able to grasp the size of the monster that you'll be dealing with.

EDIT: frameworks

I use c# for something related to that, and at first I used roll-my-own fft algorithm, then moved to ILNumerics library that uses Intel math library, and later on replaced all that with fftw.

http://ilnumerics.net/ (hm, it was free at a time)

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/  Intel Math Kernel

http://www.fftw.org/ (a simple web page, but BRUTAL performance)

EDIT: new fft engine

Since I was porting some of my code to android, I had a great working experience with a man that did something thought impossible - FFT library that is even faster than FFTW: [FFTS](https://github.com/anthonix/ffts).  My understanding of his magic is limited, but he uses codelets for various processor architectures and outperforms every library there is.

Answer (score -1):

Examining the signal power won't help for pop music. This is because contemporary pop music is highly compressed. That means that audio level compressors are applied in multiple stages of the production process to make the song appear louder. Refer to the term "loudness war" for more info. For example refer to the song "firework" by Caty Perry. The volume level is nearly constant all over the song.

Comment: This comment should not be an answer.

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard And for that very reason there's a down arrow right over there :)

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to give Olivier a chance to delete his answer before the downvote..